# Traveling from Germany to other countries by train?

Tags: trains, germany, eu

I'm going to be taking a trip to Germany in a few days.  I will be in Munich and I was considering taking the train to somewhere in Austria (Innsbruck maybe?) so I could see the Alps.

I'm wondering how difficult it is to travel between countries for something like this?  Do I need to go through the whole customs process or is it pretty much like traveling within Germany since they are both part of the EU?

Comment: Both being part of the Schengen zone is more significant for ease of travel.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - ok so is it basically just like taking the train within Germany then?  Do I even need to bring my passport?

Comment: You should, because even if both countries are in Schengen, there still can be border controls, and there have been more in the last few years because of an increasing number of migrants. Although practically those controls are not that the train stops at a certain point and everybody is checked, but rather by using foot patrols in the trains.

Comment: @dunni: At the Danish border (opposite end of Germany from the OP's plans) the usual implementation seems to be that the train is stopped at first station on Danish soil, where the police walk through the train and demand passports before the train continues. (From recent personal experience, they are _not_ happy with people who jump out of the train immediately and start running down the platform in the hope of managing to buy an onwards ticket while the train is stopped, rather than wait two hours for the next train ...)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: What happened? Did they try to stop you by force? (just being curious)

Comment: @Heinzi: Oh, it didn't get to be that dramatic. But there was some loud shouting.

Comment: you are considering Innsbruck - take a look at fares to Vienna. there is a new, cheap Railjet connection which enables Munich-Vienna in little  more than 4 hours. of course when just watching the Alps scrolling through the landscape is not enough, Innsbruck sure is the better choice.

Comment: Incidentally, you *can* see Alps without leaving Germany.

Comment: If your objective is visiting the alps, might I suggest one of the many hiking routes in the German alps near Munich : https://www.hiking-buddies.com/routes/routes_list/.

Most of the routes are can be reached in ~2-3 hours by train from Munich.

Also inside Germany, look out for regional day ticket offers if you are in a group. https://www.bahn.de/en/view/offers/regional/regional-day-tickets.shtml

Comment: > 1 million people travel around, into, and out of, germany all the time without any checks whatsoever.  I'm sure you can do it too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As long as you stay within the Schengen Area, you should be able to travel freely without any systematic passport checks, so in most cases, it looks exactly like domestic travel.

The [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) is composed of 22 of the 28 EU member states, as well as some other non-EU states such as Switzerland. Germany and Austria are both part of the Schengen Area.

Random spot checks may still happen, and in some cases systematic checks have been temporarily re-introduced, mostly due to the migrant crisis, but also sometimes for security reasons. Switzerland is also known to have a peculiar interpretation of "no systematic checks".

Even if there are no checks at the border, you should still have your passport and other paperwork with you, as you may be checked in other circumstances.

Comment: I suggest mentioning that there will be no **customs** control on goods except on Swiss border. So that the OP can carry any item without having to declare or explain at the intra-Schengen border

Comment: `Switzerland is also known to have a peculiar interpretation of "no systematic checks".` I went to Germany, Austria and France by train multiple times, I never got any border check, ever. Except when there was the following of the terrorist attacks in Paris and it was FRANCE who reintroduced the border checks. Verify your facts.

Comment: @Bregalad: Your comment did not make any sense to me, until I checked your profile and discovered that you are from Switzerland. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi I'm sorry, you're totally right it was silly to forget mentioning that I'm from Switzerland.

Comment: The Bavarian police is known for lengthy spot checks of foreigners who don't look European.

Comment: @Bregalad: did you get controlled regularly? No systematic checks mean that people are usually not checked systematically (so all people). They will control identity max one person per wagon, and not on all trains.

Comment: @Bregalad Some of my colleagues report being checked every time they drive into Switzerland with Romanian or Polish plates.  I have never experienced this with British or Baden-Württembergisher plates.  That feels like a "systematic check" to me.

Comment: Always carry your passport(If non-EU) with you. Flixbus guy refused to board a guy from Budapest to Vienna because he did not have a passport. Strangly within EU, flights won't bother for any identity document though.

Comment: @Knu8 what gives you that idea? Just last year, even as an EU resident, I had trouble boarding a plane from Berlin to Brussels because my ID got stolen in Berlin and there was no time to get a replacement, so I only had the report from the police.

Comment: @Knu8 wrong. You WILL need photo ID to board any flight within the Schengen area. You will not pass customs, but you WILL pass passport check (where in this case European ID cards are also allowed).

Comment: @jwenting if you mean passport check by immigration officers, no, for intra-Schengen flights you wouldn't go through that. The only place where your ID may be checked is at check-in or during boarding, and that is done by airline staff or their representatives, and the rules in those cases are a lot more flexible (for instance they may accept a driver's licence, as the only thing they want to check is the identity of the person matching the ticket, not their nationality or visa status). There are exceptions for a few country pairs due to the temporary reintroduction of emergency checks, though

Comment: @jcaron and they are legally required to perform those checks to ensure that no unauthorised people board their aircraft. Which effectively just defers the checks from border agents to private contractors.

Comment: @jwenting the rules are actually a lot more complex than that, there are many situations where there are no checks whatsoever, or checks only if you have checked luggage for instance. But most importantly, in this case, the types of IDs accepted are quite different, as the goal is different. However, as there are other reasons than airport checks for having your passport (as a non-EU national), you still should.

Comment: My experience is that airport practice varies from one country to another; in France, I always have to show some form of government-issued id before boarding, and sometimes have to go through immigration checks even on Schengen flights, whereas in Germany I usually don’t (and there are automated boarding gates which only require a boarding pass), and in the Netherlands I’ve even been told off (nicely) by the check-in agents for walking up to the gate holding my id along with my boarding pass!

Comment: https://www.seat61.com is a great resource

Comment: Just to clarify: you are legally obliged to bring your passport.

Answer (score 16):

You should **always** have your passport with you when out of your own country.  Within Schengen, you’ll not likely be asked for it, but it’s possible, and if you don’t have it when asked, definitely a hassle or worse.

You can probably book train trips on whatever site you use within Germany, but you can also easily do it at [Loco](https://loco2.com).

There are probably other sites.  [Rick Steves](http://ricksteves.com) has some good informational pages about trains (and other travel info) in Europe.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit too general. I am a US permanent resident. Inside the US, I carry my green card but not my passport. I take my passport with me if I plan to cross an international border.

Comment: It is still good advise. Even when you do not need to have your passport on you in the country, you should have it near, certainly border crossing. As a PR you are in 'your' country.

Comment: Well, I agree with Willeke that a permanent resident IS in her own country.  but I agree with Patricia in a way: within EU/Schengen, for a resident of one of those countries, it is quite reasonable to carry your ID instead of your passport.

Comment: @Bregalad, That’s _almost_ what I already said, but since you removed the qualifications, you are incorrect.  If person P is not a legal resident of country C and is confronted by authorities in that country, and is unable to show a valid passport, in many cases, a valid ID card will not avoid a hassle.

Comment: Again, you omit any details to determine whether your situation is the exception I mentioned or one of the other exceptions.

Comment: ID card is equivalent to a passport for those EU citizens who have them. Having neither handy is when you may get into trouble.

Comment: @Willike, yes, within the EU.  That is one of the exceptions I acknowledged.  It is not as universal as Bregalad seems to be implying.  And OP did not state whether he is an EU citizen.

Answer (score 11):

The train between Munich and Innsbruck through Kufstein has spot checks. It doesn't stop but the border police enters the train a few stations before Kufstein and walks through the carriages.

If you look suspicious, they want to check your identity so have your passport at hand. There are no customs checks.

Answer (score 9):

**It is extremely easy and there is no check.**

As a non-Schengen national I took the train between Austria and Germany twice in the last few months, and there was no suggestion that passports might be checked. I also took a bus tour that crossed the border and we were not even advised to bring passports. There are not normally checks when crossing the border between Schengen countries - that's the point of the Schengen area.

Comment: According to German law, you are supposed to *carry* identity documents (passport or national ID) at the border and present them to competent authority on demand. According to Schengen regulations, this demand should not be routinely made, but it can be made in a non-systematic manner.

Comment: @o.m I thought you were required to carry identity document at all times (not just at the border).  Is this wrong?

Comment: @MartinBonner It depends. E.g. Belgium does require valid passport or ID-card for anyone at all times (, but it is rarely checked unless police really wants to hassle you). The Netherlands (and Germany as far as I know) only require ID to be presented when needed, but they consider (for their own citizens) a drivers-license already sufficient ID for non-border checks. I'm Dutch and I never have passport on me, just drivers-license, even when traveling in Belgium, which I do almost daily. Never had a problem even though I get a spot-check at the border 4-5 times per year.

Comment: Being able to talk in the local language with the fitting accent or dialect helps in proving you are a citizen. (Even though some people have grown up in a country but are no citizen.)

Comment: @Tonny I was asking specifically about *German* law.

Comment: @MartinBonner Germany requires German citizens to hold a valid ID, not to carry it around with them, while in Germany (Gesetz über Personalausweise und den elektronischen Identitätsnachweis (Personalausweisgesetz - PAuswG) § 1 Ausweispflicht; Ausweisrecht if you wanted to look it up.

Comment: @MartinBonner In Germany, you are required to _have_ an ID, but you're not required to _carry_ it at all times (although it might result in a bit of hassle not having it ready when it's needed -- irrespective of that, having s.th. like a personalized public transit ticket might require you to carry an official ID while travelling). OTOH, _crossing any border_ in the EU requires you to carry your ID (NL police watched a friend crossing just a few meters into NL, then asked for ID, he didn't carry it, they fined him ... then DE police fined him for crossing in the other direction.)

Comment: @MartinBonner also foreigners are required to identify themselves including proving whether they are legly in the country. For a foreigner to travel around anywhere within the EU without their travel documents **is a very bad idea**.

Comment: @MartinBonner Citation for that please? And whether or not it is a bad idea, everybody does it, all the time, and has no problems.

Comment: @DJClayworth Did you mean to address that remark to Mark Johnson?  My only comments were to ask questions.

Comment: Sorry, yes, SE auto-prompted me, and you were first alphabetically.

Answer (score 8):

That's possible, and very easy.

> so is it basically just like taking the train within Germany then? Do I even need to bring my passport?

Sadly, it is not just like taking a train within Germany. In theory, it *should be*. In practice, due to developments since 2015 onwards, no. You may be, and should expect to be controlled at the border. And you had better had a passport on you then.

Regardless, you should carry your passport anyway. While at least in Germany there is no general obligation to carry ID at all times (or passport in your case, since you are not a Union member, so you have "Passpflicht", not "Ausweispflicht" -- which means ID is not sufficient), you are required to be able to prove proper ownership of a passport and you are to present it upon being asked by police *in due time*. Well, whatever that means... *in due time* (it's not defined, I am assuming something like "Sure, let me go inside my room and fetch it" would do, but "Uh, I left it in another city" might not). Not having your passport on you doesn't mean you're going to get sentenced to death, but well, it means trouble which is not really necessary during your holiday.

Plus, when crossing borders, carrying your passport is a *strict* requirement.

> somewhere in Austria (Innsbruck maybe?) so I could see the Alps.

If the intent is to *literally see* the Alps, you can do that just fine even without leaving Munich. Or, you can do it from a ton of very lovely nearby places all over the region which are easier to reach (Tegernsee or Chiemgau come to mind, or even some nearby places which you can actually reach by subway or suburban train, Munich area is quite awesome in that respect).

I'm not saying you shouldn't go to Innsbruck, it's definitively a good choice. Though depending on your luck, and depending on how late you buy, you may be surprised how much Deutsche Bahn can charge for a ticket.

Also, there's actual Alps in Germany (think e.g. Zugspitze), so you do not absolutely *need* to cross a border to see (in a sense of *walking them*) the Alps. It's somewhat closer (half an hour train time less), too.

If Kufstein (Austria) would also do instead of Innsbruck, you can possibly save quite a bit of money by getting a "Bayernticket". That's a very interesting option in any case because it's a 24-hour do-what-you-want ticket (no ICE, all within all of Bavaria, plus *almost* -- but not quite -- to the Lake Constance (2km short, that's probably on purpose!), plus some locations in Austria -- Kufstein and Salzburg among them, but *not* Innsbruck) for a very reasonable price, and if you travel with family or friends, you can add them to the ticket for a small extra charge, which makes it very worthwhile.

Comment: There are also several tickets for smaller regions of Bavaria: https://bahnland-bayern.de/de/tickets/regionale-tickets - unfortunately, I was unable to find an English translation. Conditions for these tickets are complicated, e.g. the Südostbayern-Ticket is valid for Munich-Salzburg, but only via Mühldorf (not on the usual route via Rosenheim), Monday to Friday only valid after 9 am, etc.

Comment: ... For Innsbruck, you might be interested in the "Regio-Ticket Werdenfels + Innsbruck": https://www.zugspitzarena.com/en/info-service/public-transport/regio-ticket-werdenfels-inn

Comment: You can use the BayernTicket all the way until Lindau Hbf (just check a sufficiently long distance such as Nuremberg–Lindau on bahn.de; for Munich–Lindau there is another ticket option two euros cheaper). And [Google Maps confirms that Lindau Hbf is at most 77 metres away from Lake Constance](https://goo.gl/maps/3zZBvFx1RSrYbNjQ9) (I hope the link works).

Answer (score 5):

Travelling regularly between Germany and Italy I usually get stopped at custom when entering Switzerland, a Schengen Area country but not part of the EU, but never happened when crossing Austria. There should not be any barrier except due diligence police controls on trains and at boarding in the train station.

Edit: corrected as Switzerland is actually part of Schengen Area but not part of EU
[Schengen info](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area)

Comment: Note that Switzerland, while part of the Schengen Passport-free area, isn't part of the European Customs Union, so there are frequently customs checks when crossing the border.

Comment: Couple of years ago I had the opportunity of taking a lot of train trips from Switzerland: Swiss-France, Swiss-Italy and Swiss-Austria. The police would make a round of the carriages at the border stations randomly asking for passports but I don't remember undergoing any customs checks.

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to cross the border from Germany to Austria, that is easy once you are legally inside the Schengen area (includes all of the continental EU except Croatia, Romania and Bulgaria, plus non EU members such as Switzerland and Norway). *Systematic* border checks have been abolished and the entire EU is a single customs union so there should be no ID checks and there are never customs checks regardless of whether you are on an aeroplane, on a train, in a car, on a bicycle or on foot. With the refugee arrivals of 2015, ID checks have been temporarily reintroduced at some places such as Freilassing but even if you are subject to inspection it should be a rapid one. You should, border checks or not, always have your passport with you when you leave your hotel/accomodation as both Germany and Austria have some form of ID requirement: by law, you don’t necessarily have to carry it with you at all times (at least in Germany) but you should be able to produce it rapidly upon request.

I can attest that Innsbruck is a beautiful city and should be visited. However, if your goal is really *just* the Alps then:

- they can be seen from Munich in the correct weather conditions (*Föhn* wind)
- they can be seen on any sufficiently clear day from somewhere just south of Munich such as Seeshaupt on Lake Starnberg, Weilheim i. OB. (denoted as Weilheim(Oberbay) by DB) or Murnau. Aside from the Alps there is also beautiful nature in that area.
- they extend into Germany so you can get the full mountain experience by remaining in Germany. I suggest visiting Garmisch-Partenkirchen which in itself is also a beautiful town (not legally a town though) and features the ski jump arena used for the *Vierschanzentournee*, the *Partnachklamm* gorge and various ropeways/one rack railway up onto the various surrounding mountains. Garmisch-Partenkirchen is also at the foot of the Zugspitze, Germany’s highest mountain (although the mountains you can see in Austria are higher).

Concerning your rail trip, if you’re going to Innsbruck directly, the fastest route is (sadly) the one via Rosenheim and Kufstein. This route goes through the flat land north of the Alps to Rosenheim and then through the wide Inn valley into Innsbruck. However, the train passing Garmisch-Partenkirchen also connects to Innsbruck via the Karwendelbahn. It may not be as fast but it offers wonderful scenery on your descent from Hochzirl down into Innsbruck central station. Furthermore, this trip leaves the flat country sooner and goes through smaller valleys via Farchant and Mittenwald. A discounted ticket exists to go from Munich via Garmisch-Partenkirchen to Innsbruck (but I am too out of the loop right now to give you the definite cheapest option).

Disclaimer and source: My family lives between Munich and Garmisch-Partenkirchen.

Comment: And if they do take the scenic train they should sit on the right hand side from Germany to Austria for the best views.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what others have said, theoretically there are no systematic border checks between Schengen countries. However, there are frequent "random" checks. I live in Germany and have travelled 4 or 5 times in the last year to Poland and Czech Republic via train and have been checked for a passport twice.

With respect to Austria specifically, there are [temporary border controls](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control_en) in place between Austria and Germany until November of this year. There's some diplomatic language in there about under what circumstances they *will* be in force, but suffice it to say, its not unlikely that you could be checked.